# 5x5x5 Rubik's Cube Smiley

Tags: rubiks-cube

I did some turning on my 5x5x5 Rubik's Cube and I now have the cube like on the image below. 4 times a smiley `-_-` and 2 times a solved plane. But I have no idea how I did this, does someone know the algorithm? The yellow plane is solved, the red plane has the smiley in orange and the green plane has the smiley in blue.

[image][image]

**Edit:**
The the smileys on the hidden faces are the same as in the opposite face. If you look straight at the smiley `-_-` and turn the cube $180^\circ$ on the y-axis the smiley is orientated exactly the same `-_-`. Example when turning the cube as mentioned with yellow on the table you see red/orange smileys oriented correctly and the blue/green smileys orientated $90^\circ$ wrong.

Comment: What orientation are the 'smileys' on the hidden faces? (The only square of interest is the inside edge, not the inside corners.)

Comment: That's no help, I want to know how they're oriented relative to the other smileys. "Turning the cube 180°" can lead to different results.

Comment: Does turning horizontally mean about a vertical axis or a horizontal? Saying they are the same just isn't specific enough. It would work better if you posted a second picture.

Comment: @Kendall The centers on a 3x3 can be in any 90-degree-increment orientations; imagine the outer layers of the 5x5 as a 3x3 and the smileys can be turned whatever direction you'd like.

Comment: That's not a smiley, that's a neutral face! :-| is not :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Notation**
From left layer to right layer:
$L~l~m~r~R$
From upper layer to down layer:
$U~u~M~d~D$

**Quick and Intuitive Solution**
Take white as front:
$l^2~(d~u)^2~l^2~(d~u)^2$
Take red as front and do the same:
$l^2~(d~u)^2~l^2~(d~u)^2$

Now take white as front and red top and do:
$m~u^2~m'~u^2$

Answer (score 6):

This is brute-force approach, but it will work:

I suppose you can solve the cube entirely. Then you can make smiles in the same way, just imagine that they are the solution.

If it is too hard to imagine, you can use stickers:

1. Take solved cube.
2. Put 20 stickers of 4 colours (5 red, 5 orange, 5 blue, 5 green) on 4 cube planes in a way they create smiley like on the photo.
3. Solve the cube.
4. Take stickers away.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but don't think you need that much stickers. Just $4 \cdot 5 = 20$ for the smileys.

Comment: @martijnn2008, that an improvement, yes:)